# Babel version error when react-native bundle

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, babeljs

When i try to run:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

I receive this error:

```
Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While processing preset: "C:\\..\\AppDirectory\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
```

I've tried removing node-modules directory, cleaning cache, npm install, etc, etc, etc. I've also tried installing Babel manually but the same issue persists.
I had the same error before when generating the .apk, but could solve it installing babel dependencies, now this doesn't work neither.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Appname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.54",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.54",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.54",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-upgrade": "0.0.20",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55",
    "react-native-circle-checkbox": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^6.4.0",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.7",
    "react-navigation": "^2.6.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-native": "^4.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

And this is my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/react"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json ?

Comment: @NazırDogan i've shared it. thanks

Comment: are you using babel 6 and 7 simultaneously ?  you have both packages(`"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.54",` AND `"babel-core": "^6.26.3",`) in `package.json`

Comment: i tried removing one of those and still the same...

Comment: Why you are  using   .babelrc  like this ? Classic React Native project have different .babelrc. it shoud include like this.  "presets": ["react-native"]  and you want to stage-0  then you can do like this. "presets": ["react-native", "stage-0"]